# Set theory proof: $(A\cup\ B) \subseteq \ A$ if and only if $A^c \subseteq \ B^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Task: Prove

$(A\cup\ B) \subseteq \ A$ **if and only if** $A^c \subseteq \ B^c$

My (partly) solution would be:

We have to prove 2 cases:

1.)
$(A\cup\ B) \subseteq \ A \Rightarrow A^c \subseteq \ B^c $

2.)
$A^c \subseteq \ B^c \Rightarrow (A\cup\ B) \subseteq \ A $

Case 1: 
Let x be arbitrary and $ x \in((A\cup\ B) \subseteq \ A) $

Now we know that $ x \in A $ or $ x \in B  \Rightarrow x \in A$

So if $ x \in A $, then $ x \in A $ or $ x \in B $, then $ x \in A $
From $ x \in A $ it follows that $ x \notin A^c $ 
From $ x \in B $ it follows that $ x \notin B^c $

Therefore we can conclude, that $A^c \subseteq \ B^c $

Case 2: 
Let x be arbitrary and $ x \in A^c \subseteq \ B^c $

Now we know that $ x \notin A $ and $ x \notin B$

At this point I am stuck and do not really know how to continue, I also think that my proof for Case 1 is not sufficient.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to say $x\in((A\cup B)\subseteq A)$.

Case 1 means: “prove that $A^c\subseteq B^c$ under the assumption that $A\cup B\subseteq A$”.

So you *assume* $A\cup B\subseteq A$. Then you take $x\in A^c$ and prove $x\in B^c$. If not, then $x\in B$, but then $x\in A\cup B$, so $x\in A$ by assumption: since $x\in A^c$, this is not possible. Therefore $x\in B^c$.

Case 2 means: “prove that $A\cup B\subseteq A$ under the assumption that $A^c\subseteq B^c$.

So you *assume* $A^c\subseteq B^c$. Then you take $x\in A\cup B$ and prove that $x\in A$. I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $A^c \subseteq B^c\iff B \subseteq A$. Thus if $A^c \subseteq B^c \implies B \subseteq A\implies A\cup B \subseteq A$. Conversely, if $A \cup B \subseteq A\implies A^c \subseteq (A\cup B)^c= A^c \cap B^c \subseteq A^c\implies A^c \cap B^c = A^c\implies A^c \subseteq B^c$.